# How to copy files from USB drive into HTML directory

Tags: usb, nginx

How do I copy a file from a USB drive to a directory in Ubuntu. I already have mounted the USB drive and I have also confirmed that the files are on the USB drive. I can view my files on my USB drive by using the following command:

```
ls /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
```

I need to copy my file into my html directory on the computer's drive which is in following location:

```
usr/share/nginx/html
```

Thank you for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.com! How you are copying? what I your `cp ...` command? and what you are getting one you are coping? does in your this path `usr/share/nginx/html` you have enteing the missed `/` there?

Comment: I tired the following: sudo cp /media/usb/caboose.jpg  ~/usr/share/nginx/html/

caboose.jpg is the name of the file on the USB drive that I am trying to copy into my HTML directory

Comment: do you have a dir like "~/usr/share/nginx/html/ " in your `home` directory? you should use `sudo cp /media/usb/caboose.jpg ~/usr/share/nginx/html/caboose.jpg`

Comment: usr doesn't have a *. I'm not sure if it is in my "home" directory.  The rest is correct.

Comment: I added the ~ because I read somewhere that it was needed to do the copy

Comment: I will try what you said

Comment: No `~` is point to your `home` directory, if the path `~/usr/share/nginx/html/` is exist in your home dir you could copy otherwise it will fail,

Comment: Use a different directory where you have write permissions and where nginx / `www-data` can read.  Don't go modifying `/usr/share/nginx/html` because that can be modified by package managers.

Comment: I tried:  sudo cp /media/usb/caboose.jpg  ~/usr/share/nginx/html/caboose.jpg
I got following error:    cannot create regular file ‘/home/jake/usr/share/nginx/html/caboose.jpg’: No such file or directory

Comment: @Slick you have to create that entire directory path for it to work from `/home/jake/...` - that path doesn't exist by default, so you'd have to create every directory in the path.  The alternative is to use a different path - such as `mkdir /home/jake/website/; sudo cp /media/usb/caboose.jpg ~/website/; sudo chown -R jake:www-data ~/website/` (which would then make it a much shorter string, and you then change your `nginx` config's `root` directive to be `/home/jake/website/`)

Comment: Thank you very much Kasiy and Thomas. I need to look at this a bit to try and figure it out.  By what you are saying I understand that there is a shortcut that can be used, but I still don't understand the correct syntax. I also tried to use the entire path and it still didn't work.

Comment: @Slick - In order to make the two of them know that you're thanking them and asking them anything, please, write them separately and mention their names by writing a @ in front of their names/nicknames. By doing that, they will be informed by the system that you have addressed to them. But, as far as I know, this trick works only with one name at a time. So, I repeat, you'll have to make separate comments for each one of them. Sorry for may rather off-topic comment, but I thought that you should know and it might be helpful. Good day!